# Core Data iCloud sync images

Tags: image, core-data, icloud

I want to sync via iCloud in a Core Data app. Besides some string attributes in Core Data I also want to sync images. I did a lot of research and it seems there are two approaches to achieve this. The opinions really vary so I am confused which one is the better solution?

**Approach A:**

Store images in Core Data as Binary Data.

Pros:

- Everything is synced with Core Data sync at the same time in one sync solution.
- No extra code, which is a big plus for me since I am using Ensembles Core Data Sync Framework which is working really good.

Cons:

- People say you should not sync larger data with Core Data. But what is "Allow External Storage" for ?  - I read that checking that option could lead to data loss when migrate the Core Data model. But I thought that s what it is for ? For syncing larger data... !? Should I check this or not ? Opinions vary on that...

**Approach B:**

Store images local in Document Directory and store the url to it in Core Data.

Pros:

- Avoid Approach A´s cons.

Cons:

- Two sync solutions needed working parallel. Core Data sync and UIDocument sync for the images. - Will this work really synchron? Could it be that Core Data is already synced while UIDocument sync has failed or is slower or whatever?
- Much more code. Very complex, very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are between a rock and a hard place. You researched your problem well and the options you outline are the correct ones (well, one of them is).

What I can guarantee you is that performance will deteriorate quickly if you go for option A and the images accumulate into any significant number (could be as little as several hundred, depending on size). Even loading a single image from the database could already result in noticeable lag if the size is large.

The UIDocument solution is feasible. It is really not so complicated. Users expect that text is synced immediately and images can take a while, so as long as you keep the UI responsive, this is not an issue during syncing. Indeed, you can expect syncing taking longer for the images - it's sort of logical. One more reason to separate this from the other data.

I hope this will help you make a more informed decision. Don't choose your solution based on your present level of expertise. If you can deal with Core Data, you will have no problem setting up UIDocument in sync with it ;-).

**Edit**
That being said, let me explain "Allows external storage". That means that Core Data can decide if it wants to store this attribute in an external file rather than in the database binary file. So if you decide to go with option A, this could increase performance and keep the database from becoming too large. I believe the iCloud syncing should also work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for help! Well, my app is kind of a note taking app and I learned from Flurry analytics that the users don´t have these much entries/objects. I think the highest number is around 100. So there are not some hundred objects and the users won´t make a large number of entries at once anyways. But I see from a design point of view this is not the best option right?

Comment: The problem with UIDocument sync is I can not get this to work properly. All the tutorials I found are like: Store local OR store in cloud. If the users enable/disable iCloud they kind of switch between local and cloud store and the entries are gone then. The rest of the objects which I sync with Ensembles Core Data sync avoids this problem so using both parallel seems buggy and complicated?

Comment: What I want to achieve: Sync images from Document directory via iCloud across devices to Document Directory if iCloud enabled and merge. If switch iCloud off keep the images like they are at the moment.

Comment: I had a look at ensembles. Looks like a messy solution to me (even if it works). Have you considered using native Core Data code?

Comment: I am a beginner with some basic knowledge. Most of the things I want to achieve I do in googling trying out and so on. This works for me in most of the cases, but with iCloud... I spent hours, days weeks with this... Ensembles is really great and the dealbreaker for me: it´s simple... And it does exactly what I want. Just sync... No different stores (local/cloud) and all these advanced iCloud problems... It just syncs and if you turn off iCloud, everything stays like it is... That´s what the users will expect...

Comment: With native Core Data, I had no luck dealing with all these problems like multiple accounts, switch on/off and so on...

Comment: So would Approach A to save in Binary Data be that bad In times of iOS8 and quick processors ? And what about that "Allow External Store" option? I mean what is this option for if it´s not usable for "bigger" data... I don´t sync tons of video... just 3-5 images at the same time i guess...

Comment: Thanks! I already read about what this option does. The thing is that people say you should not use it because it causes errors when doing lighweight migration and that you also can t do queries, which I do not want... But still there are many opinions saying "don´t use this option"... So if I go with Approach A I should use that option yes ?

Comment: I have used it a couple of times, including iCloud, without problems. But nobody can guarantee that it will play nice with your 3rd party framework. If you think that there won't be so many images to degrade performance, go with your simple solution.